# How to put data into mysql database [error]

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code:

```
 //INSERT COMPANY TO DATABASE
    if($result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `$company_table` (`company_name`, `company_nip`, `company_regon`, `owner_name`, `owner_surname`, `company_post`, `company_city`, `company_street`) VALUES ('$company_name_user', '$company_nip_user', '$company_regon_user', '$owner_name_user', '$owner_surname_user', '$company_post_user', '$company_city_user', '$company_street_user'"))
        {

//pass

 }else
    {
        echo "error 3<br> $user_nick";
        echo $connect->connect_error;
    }
```

This code always showing me "error 3"

This is my mysql table structure
[image: mysql structure]

Comment: If you insert php variables directly into an SQL query, you are completely open to SQL injection attacks. You should consider "mysqli :: prepared statements", they are much more powerful and better.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will fix it but that's not answer for my question

Comment: "Error 3" doesn't really tell you much about what failed, does it?  What data access technology are you using?  That technology should have a way for checking for errors after executing a query.  Which are not *connection errors*, as the code appears to only be looking for those currently.

Comment: @KamilBarwiński: *"I will fix it but that's not answer for my question"* - Unless that happens to be the root cause of the problem, syntax errors stemming from poorly structured/managed SQL code that would be corrected by using prepared statements with query parameters.  If you currently don't know the cause of the problem then it seems counterproductive to insist that potential solutions are wrong.

Comment: Can you publish the text of the error you are receiving from SQL or PHP?  can you publish the text of the error you are receiving from SQL or PHP? Because Error 3 doesn't really tell us anything about an existing problem. @KamilBarwiński

Comment: right but why this is show me nothing: printf( $connect->connect_error); @PetrFořtFru-Fru

Comment: You must use: `$connect->error;` @KamilBarwiński

Comment: Your closing parentheses for your list of values in your SQL INSERT statement is on the wrong side of your double quote. To @PetrFořtFru-Fru point, parameterizing your query would have made this more visible since you wouldn't have to bobble around single/double quotes.

Comment: Last quotation mark should be between the last two parenthesis. You have a syntax error.

Comment: Remove the apostrophes that delimit the php variables in the sql query. Enclose the PHP variables in the sql query in curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer PDO myself, but using mysqli to safely insert data to prevent injection attacks. The table name is checked separately using a whitelist because you cannot parameterize it as you do the other variables. Also, separating your statement onto different lines (such as query variable), makes it easier to catch the syntax error you have.

```
$table_options = array("tbl_companies", "tbl_stuff", "tbl_things");

if (in_array($user_selected_table, $table_options) ){
    
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$user_selected_table` (`company_name`, `company_nip`, `company_regon`, `owner_name`, `owner_surname`, `company_post`, `company_city`, `company_street`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $company_name_user, $company_nip_user, $company_regon_user, $owner_name_user, $owner_surname_user, $company_post_user, $company_city_user, $company_street_user);
    
    
    $stmt->execute();
}else{
    // invalid table name
}
```

Comment: You're right. I've updated my example to check the table name against a whitelist instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO company_table(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $company_name_user, $company_nip_user, $company_region_user);
if($stmt->execute()){
   //Carry out something to show the insert was successful
}
$stmt->close();
```

Please take a look at my example above.

- `$connect` is your database connection.
- field 1, 2, 3 - these are your table columns. Define these here.
- ? these comma separated question marks are your values which will be defined in bind_param.
- bind_param, the "s" is for string and these represent the values in your query `?` and you should use i where an integer. You then declare your variables as shown.
- Then you run an execute, and close the query.

I hope this helps. This is how I do my SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks. Was copying it from my own code with about 15 variable types , one of the easiest mistakes to make is adding too many or too little S or ?